# R: reshape data from column to row and add additional data based on name

Tags: r, join, dataframe, reshape

I am looking for a way to reshape the following sample `data`

```
data <- structure(list(id = c(2L, 5L, 7L), name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Test1","Test10", "Test8"), class = "factor"), source = structure(c(1L,3L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "T", "Z"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "name", "source"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

 id   name source
1  2  Test1      A
2  5 Test10      Z
3  7  Test8      T
```

into the following structure

```
row.names   1.1    2.1     3.1
id            2      5       7
name      Test1 Test10   Test8
source        A      Z       T
```

and how could I add a second data.frame say, `data2` based on the name to `data` (only the data that contains a matching name)?

```
data2 <- structure(list(name = structure(1L, .Label = "adddata", class = "factor"), Test1 = 10L, Test10 = 12L, Test8 = 17L, Test12 = 7L), .Names = c("name", "Test1", "Test10", "Test8", "Test12"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))

data2
   name   Test1 Test10 Test8 Test12
1 adddata    10     12    17      7
```

So that in the end something like the following data.frame which contains only matching names (Test12 from `data2` is left out) is the case

```
datanew
  row.names   1.1    2.1   3.1
1        id     2      5     7
2      name Test1 Test10 Test8
3    source     A      Z     T
4   adddata    10     12    17
```

**EDIT**

I just realised that my input data contains nested lists like this. Is there a way to implement this?

```
data <- structure(list(`1.1` = structure(list(id = structure(2, .Dim = c(1L, 1L)), name = structure("Test1", .Dim = c(1L, 1L)), source = structure("A", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = c("id", "name", "source")), `2.1` = structure(list(id = structure(5, .Dim = c(1L, 1L)), name = structure("Test10", .Dim = c(1L, 1L)), source = structure("Z", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = c("id", "name", "source")), `3.1` = structure(list(id = structure(7, .Dim = c(1L, 1L)), name = structure("Test8", .Dim = c(1L, 1L)), source = structure("T", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = c("id", "name", "source"))), .Names = c("1.1", "2.1", "3.1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("id", "name", "source"))

'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ 1.1:List of 3
  ..$ id    : num [1, 1] 2
  ..$ name  : chr [1, 1] "Test1"
  ..$ source: chr [1, 1] "A"
 $ 2.1:List of 3
  ..$ id    : num [1, 1] 5
  ..$ name  : chr [1, 1] "Test10"
  ..$ source: chr [1, 1] "Z"
 $ 3.1:List of 3
  ..$ id    : num [1, 1] 7
  ..$ name  : chr [1, 1] "Test8"
  ..$ source: chr [1, 1] "T"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could transpose the first dataset ('data') and `rbind` the output ('d1') with the columns that in 'data2' that we subset using the `match` between the column 'name' in 'data' and the column names of 'data2'

```
  d1 <- as.data.frame(t(data), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  res <- rbind(d1, setNames(data2[match(data$name, names(data2))], names(d1)))
  rownames(res)[4] <- as.character(data2$name)
  res
  #           V1     V2    V3
  #id          2      5     7
  #name    Test1 Test10 Test8
  #source      A      Z     T
  #adddata    10     12    17
```

Or another option is join from `data.table`

```
  library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
  DT <- setDT(data)[melt(data2, id.var='name', value.name='adddata', 
           variable.name='name')[-1], on='name', nomatch=0]
  DT
  #   id   name source adddata
  #1:  2  Test1      A      10
  #2:  5 Test10      Z      12
  #3:  7  Test8      T      17
```

I would keep in this format rather than transpose it as the columns are of different classes.  If we transpose, the numeric and non-numeric elements get mixed together in a column and the class will be either `factor` or `character`

```
 t(DT)
```

#### Update

Based on the edited "data", we can `unlist` the `list` and convert to 'data.frame'.  Then, we can use the steps as before.

```
 data <- setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(data), ncol=3, 
               byrow=TRUE)), row.names(data))
 DT <- setDT(data)[melt(data2, id.var='name', value.name='adddata', 
            variable.name='name')[-1], on='name', nomatch=0]
 DT
 #   id   name source adddata
 #1:  2  Test1      A      10
 #2:  5 Test10      Z      12
 #3:  7  Test8      T      17
```

Comment: thanks @akrun. I however just realised that `data` contains nested lists and is not a common data.frame (I edited the input data). Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: @nebuloso Updated the post